# Edit input name when chceckbox clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I try to edit name field for the specific input. I need this to get all the variables from this site and add them to my invoice script. I have two divs with client select and service select
HTML:

```
     <div class="service-select">
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT id,service_name,quantity,net_price,gross_value FROM service";

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <div class='single-service-<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'>
        <input type='checkbox' name=''>
        <input type="text" name="service_name" class='name' value="<?php echo $row["service_name"]; ?>" placeholder='NAZWA USŁUGI' disabled/>
        <label>Ilość:</label><input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>" placeholder='ILOŚĆ' disabled/>
        <label>Cena netto:</label><input type="number" name="net_price" value="<?php echo $row["net_price"]; ?>" placeholder='CENA NETTO' disabled/>
      </div>
      <?php
            }
          $result->free();
        }
      ?>
    </div>

    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

    for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var div = this.parentNode;
        var name_input = div.getElementsByClassName("name");
        var name = name_input.name;
        var parent_div = div.parentNode;
        var x = div.childNodes;
        console.log(name_input);
        if (parent_div.className == 'service-select') {
          if (name_input.name != 'service_chcecked[]') {
            name_input.name = 'service_chcecked[]';
          }
          else {
            name_input.name = 'service_name';
          }
        }
        else {
          if (name != 'client_chcecked[]') {
            name_input.name = ['client_chcecked[]'];
          }
          else {
            name_input.name = ['client_name'];
          }
        }
        for(y=0; y < x.length; y++) {
          if(x[y].type === "number" || x[y].type === "text") {
            x[y].disabled = !x[y].disabled;
          }
        }
      }, false);
    };
```

My problem is that currently the given name is added to the div :/

Comment: But sorry, to be honest, I just don't follow what you are trying to do, and your question description text isn't shedding any light on the matter. I see a lot of issues in that raw long-hand javascript, many which could be avoided by using a framework like jquery... but, I still cannot figure out what your "end result" is supposed to be here.

Comment: writes all services and clients to separate divs with each of the vents there is a checkbox which turns on and off inputs for editing when the checkbox is clicked I would like to add a customer / service name to the table that I could download in PHP and display the customer / service data on the finished invoice